# ionic app ajax call works in browser with "ionic serve" but not on ios device with "ionic upload"

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

Breaking my head on this one for 3 days already. The app works in the browser but not on the ios device. If I alert the data from the ajax call it is returned null on the ios device.

REGISTER.HTML

```
<div ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
      <div class="list">
        <span>test{{responseMessage}}</span>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Email</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Password retype</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="retypepassword" placeholder="Retype password">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="register()">Register</button><br>
      </div>
    </div>
```

APP.JS

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $http) {

$scope.register = function () {

        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "https://www.dummylink.com/app/php/register.php",
            data: {
                username: $scope.username,
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password,
                retypepassword: $scope.retypepassword
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
        request.success(function (data) {
              $scope.responseMessage = data;
        });
        request.error(function (data) {
              alert(data);
        });
}
```

})

Comment: are you using http or https for your network calls?

Comment: I don't really know, where can I check this?

Comment: You have https://dummy link.com in your example but are you using http:// or https:// in your code

Comment: When I tried this tutorial (http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/codeproject/posting-data-from-ionic-app-to-php-server/) it worked on my device but got a header error in the browser

Comment: Is your request to localhost?

Comment: If I alert the response data from the ajax call it has the value null..

Comment: That's because error is populated

Comment: yes it is to localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a big thanks to tommybananas for trying to help me! Eventually the problem wasn't CORS related.

The problem was that my ssl certificate wasn't installed correctly. I removed it and installed it again. Now everything is working!